# Result of VBA code not visible in textbox in Access

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I use Access to maintain a list (with details) of cases I work on (I am a legal professional).

I want to add a unique case identifier to every case. I use a form to enter the data in the database.

I wrote this very simple code to add the Case ID nr:

```
Private Sub Command81_Click()
    If Not IsNull(Me.Case_ID) Then
        DoCmd.CancelEvent
    Else
        Command81.Enabled = True
        Me.Case_ID = Me.Combo321 + Format(Me.[Date Original Event], "yymmdd") + Format(Time, "hhmmss")
    End If
End Sub
```

The idea is I fill the different fields in the form and then click a button to add the case ID (listed in the textbox (in the form) and field (in the database) called 'Case_ID').

When I click the button it should check whether there is already a case ID. If there is it will not create a new one. If there is none yet a new case ID will be created based on the country where the case happened (Combo321) + the date when the original event happened + time I created the case ID.

(There is a reason why the case ID is so complicated, but that doesn't matter for the purpose of my question.).

The code works like a charm, except: when I click the button nothing happens in the form. The Case ID only appears in the relevant textbox in the form after I click on it (after the Case ID was created).

Is there anything I can add to the code to make the Case ID appear in the textbox in the form when it is created, without having to click the text box?

Answer (score 0):

What is the recordsource of your form?
You really need to update/value the CaseId in the table
underlying your form.